# "Less/more than value" search in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have 3 field in my document:

- id
- title
- txt

I have inserted several records into the index(articles) with the following code:

```
$es = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = [
    'index'=>'articles',
    'type'  => 'article'
];

for ($i=1; $i<50000; $i++) {
    $params['body'] = [ 
       'id' => $i, 
       'title'=>'some title '.$i, 
       'txt'=>'some text '.$i
    ];
    $response = $es->index($params);
}
```

Now I want to retrieve records where `id > 20000`. 
How can perform filters like this, in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your `id` field is saved as `long`, you can do this by executing a GET request to `<ES_HOST>:9200/articles/article/_mapping`,

Then you can run this query to get the relevant ids:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "id": {
                        "gt": 20000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```